# Triggering log out methods on time out

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a set of methods that clear cache data on log out, is there an easy way to trigger these functions when the session times out?  I have updated my web config to have a time out of 1 minute for testing.

The issue i'm having is certain things displayed are meant to persist based on the user logged in, if the session times out and a new user logs in they will see the previous users information. This does not happen on log out because of the logic in place.

I don't need an answer but a pointer in the right direction on how to handle time out functions.

Comment: It's not the page that times out, its the session. A page is disconnected from the server, so it isn't firing any sort of timeout event. The server simply interrogates the session's last request, compares it with the current datetime when a new request is made, and determines whether or not the session has timed out.

Comment: Thank you, updated the question with the correct context.  That is what I mean, but I was speaking from the users point of view, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your global.asax:

```
 public void Session_OnEnd()
 {
  //Find user's data using SessionId and remove it
 }
```

Comment: Won't this trigger on log out now as well? Setting a break point there show this method is triggered on log out as well as time out, lets say I want different things to happen based on log out or session time out, how would you handle this.  The variables used for log out cannot be reached here, I am working on some one else's code so this is a learning experience for me.

Edit: This code block is never reached on session time out, it is only reached when the user chooses log out.

Comment: This is as close as you are going to get, I'm afraid, unless you want to start polling/hammering your DB to determine when a session has expired. You could add a session variable to differentiate between a log out and when a request is made under the context of an expired session.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, this is a minor bug but if it was an easy fix I would go for it.  This seems like more work to redesign than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was simply ClearAllSessionKeys on log on instead of on session time out.  This had the same effect and fixed my issue.